# VBA to Randomly assign names to groups without repeating

Tags: vba, excel, random

[image: Name List][image: Leader List]I am looking for a macro that will randomly assign names into a group. There are 16 groups and they each need 10 names randomly assigning to them. The list of names is on a different sheet and ideally I would just like to run a macro which will paste 10 random names from the list into each group without any repeats. Is this possible? I haven't had any luck finding a solution anywhere else.

Comment: Please post an image of what you have and what you want to have

Comment: So far I have only tried using formulas but that repeats entries

Comment: As AnalystCave.com said, post pictures and clarify this question because we're not psychic.

Comment: I have added photos as requested, there is a list of 160 names on sheet 1 and team leaders on sheet 2, I'm looking for a macro to randomly assign the names from sheet one into the blank spaces on sheet 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the following assumptions:

1. Person names are in Column A on sheet named "Persons", and column B here is free for anything
2. Tables of teams are in sheet called "Tables", and "Team Leader 1" is in A1, "Team Leader 2" is in B1, etc, "Team Leader 9" is in A13, "Team Leader 10" is in B13, etc
3. List of persons is continous list with no black spaces before the next person
4. You make a command button and assign it to CreateTeams_BtnClick() from the following code:

:) inserted smiley because code brackets go haywire when inserting after numbered list

```
Public Sub CreateTeams_BtnClick()
CreateTeams
End Sub
Private Sub CreateTeams()
Dim teamsSheet, personsSheet As Worksheet
Set teamsSheet = Worksheets("Teams")
Set personsSheet = Worksheets("Persons")


personsSheet.Range("A:A").Copy Destination:=personsSheet.Range("B:B")

Dim numPersons As Integer
numPersons = personsSheet.Range("B:B").End(xlDown).row

Dim startRow As Integer
startRow = 2
Dim startCol As Integer
startCol = 1
Dim personNumber As Integer

For i = 1 To 16
    For j = 1 To 10
        personNumber = Int((numPersons - 1 + 1) * Rnd() + 1)
        teamsSheet.Cells(startRow, startCol).Value = personsSheet.Cells(personNumber, 2).Value
        personsSheet.Cells(personNumber, 2).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        numPersons = numPersons - 1
        startRow = startRow + 1
    Next j

    If i < 8 Then
        startRow = 2
        startCol = startCol + 1
    ElseIf i = 8 Then
        startRow = 14
        startCol = 1
    Else
        startRow = 14
        startCol = startCol + 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Does anyone know how to effectively paste code in stackExchage, so that indents are applied correctly? the first indent will always be avoided as it is treated as 4 spaces for code. Is there any <code></code> or something? And why do I have to add a sentance after numbered lists to get code format?

Comment: @gudal you can paste a chunk of code, select it and use `CTRL`+`K` in order to quickly insert a code block.